# Apply a texture to an image in SVG

Tags: svg, textures, svg-filters

I'm trying to apply a texture to an image

**Original**

[image]

**Texture**

[image]

**Result** (made with PHP GD)

[image]

But with SVG, the closest I got is this result

```html
<svg preserveAspectRatio="none" width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
    <defs>
    
      <filter id="texture">
        <feImage href="https://i.imgur.com/pjWcnJs.jpg" result="texture-img"/>
        <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="texture-img" mode="multiply"/>
      </filter>
    
    </defs>
    
    <g>
        <g filter="url(#texture)">
            <image x="0" y="0" href="https://i.imgur.com/oVEdsQt.png" opacity="1" width="500" height="500" />
        </g>
    </g>
    
</svg>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/unloco/168z3og2/4/)

Is there another way which won't texturize transparent pixels?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution which is to pass the texture through a composite filter which would crop it to the source image

```html
<svg preserveAspectRatio="none" width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
    <defs>
    
      <filter id="texture">
        <feImage href="https://i.imgur.com/pjWcnJs.jpg" result="texture-img"/>
        <feComposite in2="SourceGraphic" operator="in" in="texture-img" result="composite"/>
        <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="composite" mode="multiply"/>
      </filter>
    
    </defs>
    
    <g>
        <g filter="url(#texture)">
            <image x="0" y="0" href="https://i.imgur.com/oVEdsQt.png" opacity="1" width="500" height="500" />
        </g>
    </g>
    
</svg>
```

To tile the texture, I used `feTile` like this

```html
<svg preserveAspectRatio="none" width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
    <defs>
    
      <filter id="texture" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
        <feImage href="https://i.imgur.com/gWH7NLm.jpg" result="texture-img" width="256" height="256"/>
        <feTile in="texture-img" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" result="tile" ></feTile>
        <feComposite in2="SourceGraphic" operator="in" in="tile" result="composite"/>
        <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="composite" mode="multiply"/>
      </filter>
    
    </defs>
    
    <g>
        <g filter="url(#texture)">
            <image x="0" y="0" href="https://i.imgur.com/oVEdsQt.png" opacity="1" width="500" height="500" />
        </g>
    </g>
    
</svg>
```

I got the idea by checking how `inkscape` applies material textures